# My background colors do not fill the width of the screen

Tags: html, css

In my css code i am trying to create a footer and my background color will not fill the width of the screen(the same happened earlier)

Here is what it looks like. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VxYU.png)

html code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Sodo Sans";
    src: url("/fonts/sodo-sans-regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
         url("/fonts/sodo-sans-regular.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;


}

body{
    font-family: "Sodo Sans", sans-serif;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

nav{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}

nav ul{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
}

p{
    color: #555;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;

}

.row{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.col-2{
    flex-basis: 50%;
    min-width: 300px;
}

.col-2 img{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    width: 450px;
}
.col-2 h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 25px 0;
}

.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #069972;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    border-radius: 30px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover{
    background: inherit
}


.header{
    background: radial-gradient(#fff,#ffd6d6);
}

.header .row{
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.catagories{
    margin: 70px 0;
}

.col-3{
    flex-basis: 30%;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.col-3 img{
    width: 100%;
}

.small-container{
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.col-4{
    flex-basis: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.col-4 img{
    width: 100%;
}
.title{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 80px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: #555;
}

.title::after{
    content: '';
    background: #073eb6;
    width: 80px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h4{
    color: #555;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.col-4 p{
    font-size: 14px;
}

.col-4:hover{
    top: 5px;
}
/*------------- offer -------------*/
.offer{
    background: radial-gradient(#fff, #ffd6d6);
    margin-top: 80px;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.col-2 .offer-img{
    padding: 50px;
}
small{
    color: #555;
}

/*------------- testimonial -------------*/
.testimonial{
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.testimonial .col-3{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.testimonial .col-3 img{
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.testimonial .col-3:hover{
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.fa.fa-quote-left{
    font-size: 34px;
    color: orange;
}

.col-3 p{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 12px 0;
    color: #777;
}

.testimonial .col-3 h3{
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 19px;
}

/*------------- brands -------------*/

.brands{
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.col-5{
    width: 160px;
}

.col-5 img{
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    transition: 0.25s;
}

.col-5 img:hover{
    filter: grayscale(0);
}


/*------------- footer -------------*/
.footer{
    background: #000;
    color: #8a8a8a;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 60px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Your Ecommerce Name.</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo.png" width="125px" alt="My logo">
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <img src="cart.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <h1>Eccomerce</h1>
                <p>
                    Ecommerce has become an increasingly popular way for businesses<br>
                    and individuals to buy and sell goods and services online. With the <br>
                    rise of the internet and advancements in technology, it is now easier<br>
                    than ever to set up an online store and reach a global audience.<br>
                    Ecommerce allows for a more convenient and cost-effective way to<br>
                    conduct transactions, and has opened up new opportunities for <br>
                    entrepreneurs and consumers alike.
                </p>

                <a href=""class="btn"> Explore now! &#8594;</a>
                </div>

            <div class="col-2">
                <img src="reference.png" alt="Your Reference photo.">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!---------- featured catagories ---------->
    <div class="catagories">
        <div class="small-container">   
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="catagory.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="catagory.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="catagory.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!---------- featured products ---------->
    <div class="small-container">
        <h2 class="title">Featured Products</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="product.png" alt="">
                <h4>Product name</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="product.png" alt="">
                <h4>Product name</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="product.png" alt="">
                <h4>Product name</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="product.png" alt="">
                <h4>Product name</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <h2 class="title"> Latest Products</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="product.png" alt="">
                <h4>Product name</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="product.png" alt="">
                <h4>Product name</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="product.png" alt="">
                <h4>Product name</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="product.png" alt="">
                <h4>Product name</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="product.png" alt="">
                <h4>Product name</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="product.png" alt="">
                <h4>Product name</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="product.png" alt="">
                <h4>Product name</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="product.png" alt="">
                <h4>Product name</h4>
                <p>Price</p>
            </div>
    </div>
<!---------- offers ---------->
    <div class="offer">
        <div class="small-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <img src="product.png" class ="offer-img" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <p>Special Offer!</p>
                    <h1>Product</h1>
                    <small>Information about product<br></small>
                    <a href="" class="btn">Buy Now! &#8594</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!---------- testimonial ---------->
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="small-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3"> 
                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>

                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                    </div>

                    <img src="person1.jpg" alt="">
                    <h3>Rachel Gardener</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3"> 
                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>

                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star-o" ></i>
                    </div>
                    <img src="person2.jpg" alt="">
                    <h3>Micheal Grove</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3"> 
                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>

                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star-half-o" ></i>
                    </div>

                    <img src="person3.jpg" alt="">
                    <h3>Orion Maxwell</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    
<!---------- brands ---------->
    <div class="brands">
        <div class="small-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="spotify.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="twitter.png" alt="">
                </div>  
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="adidas.png" alt="">
                </div>  
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="xbox.png" alt="">
                </div>  
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="youtube.png" alt="">
                </div>  
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="microsoft.png" alt="">
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!---------- brands ---------->

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="footer-col-1">
                    <h3>Download Our App</h3>
                    <p>Download app.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-col-2">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="">
                    <p>Download app.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-col-3">
                    <h3>Useful Links</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Coupons</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Return Policy</li>
                        <li>Join Affiliates</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-col-4">
                    <h3>Follow Us</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Facebook</li>
                        <li>Twiiter</li>
                        <li>Instagram</li>
                        <li>Youtube</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am very new to html/css coding and any help is really appreciated, also if there is an answer somewhere please direct me to it as i dont really know how to describe the problem.

Comment: there's the chance that the element containing your footer has padding.. even the body itself. Maybe share the whole page so it will be clear.

Comment: Hi diego, i have now edited added the rest of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing that your `.footer` doesn't fill with its black background color is defined as padding left and right for the `.small-container` element that happens to be the container of your elements including the footer as its last child.

To make your footer take the whole width,
At first I tried changing this rule:

```
.small-container{
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
```

To this by commenting the padding part:

```
.small-container{
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    /*
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    */
}
```

But the side effect, was the padding was lacking in general.

So I restored the css rule above and just moved the footer element ***outside*** of that container. So that it doesn't get the padding but the rest of the document does.

*As a side note you were missing also a closing div at the end in your body.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Sodo Sans";
  src: url("/fonts/sodo-sans-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("/fonts/sodo-sans-regular.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  font-family: "Sodo Sans", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
}

p {
  color: #555;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.col-2 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.col-2 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  width: 450px;
}

.col-2 h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #069972;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: inherit
}

.header {
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, #ffd6d6);
}

.header .row {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.catagories {
  margin: 70px 0;
}

.col-3 {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.col-3 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.small-container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.col-4 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.col-4 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 80px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #555;
}

.title::after {
  content: '';
  background: #073eb6;
  width: 80px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h4 {
  color: #555;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.col-4 p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.col-4:hover {
  top: 5px;
}


/*------------- offer -------------*/

.offer {
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, #ffd6d6);
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.col-2 .offer-img {
  padding: 50px;
}

small {
  color: #555;
}


/*------------- testimonial -------------*/

.testimonial {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.testimonial .col-3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.testimonial .col-3 img {
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.testimonial .col-3:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.fa.fa-quote-left {
  font-size: 34px;
  color: orange;
}

.col-3 p {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  color: #777;
}

.testimonial .col-3 h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 19px;
}


/*------------- brands -------------*/

.brands {
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 160px;
}

.col-5 img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.col-5 img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}


/*------------- footer -------------*/

.footer {
  background: #000;
  color: #8a8a8a;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 60px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Your Ecommerce Name.</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="logo.png" width="125px" alt="My logo">
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <img src="cart.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
          <h1>Eccomerce</h1>
          <p>
            Ecommerce has become an increasingly popular way for businesses<br> and individuals to buy and sell goods and services online. With the <br> rise of the internet and advancements in technology, it is now easier<br> than ever to set up an online
            store and reach a global audience.<br> Ecommerce allows for a more convenient and cost-effective way to<br> conduct transactions, and has opened up new opportunities for <br> entrepreneurs and consumers alike.
          </p>

          <a href="" class="btn"> Explore now! &#8594;</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2">
          <img src="reference.png" alt="Your Reference photo.">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!---------- featured catagories ---------->
  <div class="catagories">
    <div class="small-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <img src="catagory.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <img src="catagory.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <img src="catagory.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!---------- featured products ---------->
  <div class="small-container">
    <h2 class="title">Featured Products</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="product.png" alt="">
        <h4>Product name</h4>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="product.png" alt="">
        <h4>Product name</h4>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="product.png" alt="">
        <h4>Product name</h4>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="product.png" alt="">
        <h4>Product name</h4>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <h2 class="title"> Latest Products</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="product.png" alt="">
        <h4>Product name</h4>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="product.png" alt="">
        <h4>Product name</h4>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="product.png" alt="">
        <h4>Product name</h4>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="product.png" alt="">
        <h4>Product name</h4>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="product.png" alt="">
        <h4>Product name</h4>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="product.png" alt="">
        <h4>Product name</h4>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="product.png" alt="">
        <h4>Product name</h4>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="product.png" alt="">
        <h4>Product name</h4>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!---------- offers ---------->
    <div class="offer">
      <div class="small-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <img src="product.png" class="offer-img" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>Special Offer!</p>
            <h1>Product</h1>
            <small>Information about product<br></small>
            <a href="" class="btn">Buy Now! &#8594</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!---------- testimonial ---------->
    <div class="testimonial">
      <div class="small-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>

            <div class="rating">
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            </div>

            <img src="person1.jpg" alt="">
            <h3>Rachel Gardener</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>

            <div class="rating">
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
            </div>
            <img src="person2.jpg" alt="">
            <h3>Micheal Grove</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>

            <div class="rating">
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
            </div>

            <img src="person3.jpg" alt="">
            <h3>Orion Maxwell</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!---------- brands ---------->
    <div class="brands">
      <div class="small-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5">
            <img src="spotify.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <img src="twitter.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <img src="adidas.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <img src="xbox.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <img src="youtube.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <img src="microsoft.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!---------- brands ---------->
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="footer-col-1">
          <h3>Download Our App</h3>
          <p>Download app.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-col-2">
          <img src="logo.png" alt="">
          <p>Download app.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-col-3">
          <h3>Useful Links</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Coupons</li>
            <li>Blogs</li>
            <li>Return Policy</li>
            <li>Join Affiliates</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-col-4">
          <h3>Follow Us</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Twiiter</li>
            <li>Instagram</li>
            <li>Youtube</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi diego, that sounds right, but when added to my code, It does nothing? I also tried to comment out the padding for .container to see if that changed anything. All that was changed was my text at the top being next to the margin.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are having that strange behaviour. Anyway your html was a bit malformed missing a closing div at the end of the body. I updated my answer with some new insights.